# VB.NET Scope with Shared: Subs and Functions and Web Methods

Tags: vb.net, scope

.NET Gurus,

I have picked up another developers work and I have created a `Class Level Public Property boolean isNewValue`

However, I cannot access this `Property` from the `"Shared" Subs` or `Functions` that are `Public` or `<WebMethods>` that are `Public Shared Functions.`

I do not understand why, could someone explain?

```
' Public Property scoped as Public in the Public Class Class_Name
Public Property isNewValueCode As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isNewValueCode
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _isNeValuewSrvCode = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Later on in the code I have:

```
Shared Function GetDataItem(ByRef db As myEntities) As CodeDataItem


    THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO BE ADD AN IF
    If isNewValueCode Then 'Cannot see the isNewValueCode

          Dim data As New CodeDataItem
          Dim code = db.tbl_services.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.id = TargetID)
          If (Not code Is Nothing) Then
                data = New CodeDataItem(code)
          End If
    Else
         'New code going against different db.tables in Entity Context
    End If


    Return data
End Function



enter code here
```

Comment: Add more info to help resolve issue.

Comment: Company Policies, have to be discrete in sharing code and scrub the code.  ;)

Comment: Just in case you're making this mistake, don't be confused by the term `Shared`...it has nothing to do with scope.  It's just the equivalent of `static` in most other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access non shared class members from shared functions without an instance of that class. So to be able to access `isNewValueCode` you need an instance of what ever class the property belongs to. 
Depending on you requirements you could possibly change the property to be `shared` also, but than it would no longer be a member of any instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have something simular to this:

```
Private _isNewValueCode As Boolean
Private _isNeValuewSrvCode As Boolean

Public Property isNewValueCode As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isNewValueCode
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _isNeValuewSrvCode = value
    End Set
End Property
```

You have a couple of options here, you can make isNewValue and it's private constructors shared like so:

```
Private Shared _isNewValueCode As Boolean
Private Shared _isNeValuewSrvCode As Boolean

Public Shared Property isNewValueCode As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isNewValueCode
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _isNeValuewSrvCode = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Or *Assuming* `isNeValuewSrvCode` is a copy paste error and you really wanted to assign it back to the same variable, you could simply do this:

```
Public Shared Property isNewValueCode As Boolean
```

Take a look at the [MSDN Description of shared properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx) for more info on what exactly the `shared` keyword does.